# Determining the corresponding local field

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

Let $p$ be an odd prime number. Then there are three quadratic extensions of $\mathbb{Q}_p$. Assume that $t$ is a nonresidue module $p$, then these three extensions can be obtained by adjoining $\sqrt{t}$, $\sqrt{p}$ and $\sqrt{pt}$. Let $K/\mathbb{Q}$ be a Galois extension, for which the ramification index of $p$ is equal to $e=1$, and the inertia degree is equal to $f=2$. Let $\mathfrak{p}$ be a prime above $p$, then $K_{\mathfrak{p}}/\mathbb{Q}_p$ is an extension of degree $2$. But I can not decide to which of those three extensions it corresponds to. How can I find the corresponding extension? Which of these three extensions $\mathbb{Q}_p(\sqrt{t}), \mathbb{Q}_p(\sqrt{p}), \mathbb{Q}_p(\sqrt{pt})$ is obtained?

Edit: The comment by reuns answered my question. Now I have another similar question. How can we determine the corresponding extension, when $e=2$ and $f=1$? (The new question in detail: I mean Let $K/\mathbb{Q}$ be a Galois extension, for which the ramification index of $p$ is equal to $e=2$, and the inertia degree is equal to $f=1$. Let $\mathfrak{p}$ be a prime above $p$, then $K_{\mathfrak{p}}/\mathbb{Q}_p$ is an extension of degree $2$. But I can not decide to which of those three extensions it corresponds to. How can I find the corresponding extension? Which of these three extensions $\mathbb{Q}_p(\sqrt{t}), \mathbb{Q}_p(\sqrt{p}), \mathbb{Q}_p(\sqrt{pt})$ is obtained?)

Comment: Only $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{t})$ is unramified ($e=1$). $1/e$ is telling the valuation of the uniformizer (given $v(p)=1$). $\sqrt{p}$ and $\sqrt{pt}$ have valuation $1/2$ (and are uniformizer of the extension they generate).

Comment: @reuns Thank you. This answers my question. I will add a little edit to my question.

Comment: $ef= [K_P:\Bbb{Q}_p]$ means that the ramified extensions are totally ramified $(f=1$)

Comment: @reuns I add this new question. How can we determine the corresponding extension, when $e=2$ and $f=1$?

Comment: Determine what from what?

Comment: @reuns I add(~copied) detailed versions of my new question in the parentheses. You can see it here (Let $K/\mathbb{Q}$ be a Galois extension, for which the ramification index of $p$ is equal to $e=2$, and the inertia degree is equal to $f=1$. Let $\mathfrak{p}$ be a prime above $p$, then $K_{\mathfrak{p}}/\mathbb{Q}_p$ is an extension of degree $2$. But I can not decide to which of those three extensions it corresponds to. How can I find the corresponding extension? Which of these three extensions $\mathbb{Q}_p(\sqrt{t}), \mathbb{Q}_p(\sqrt{p}), \mathbb{Q}_p(\sqrt{pt})$ is obtained?)

Comment: You can't decide because you didn't understand what is $e,f, ef=n$. I explained it above.

Comment: @reuns for $\mathbb{Q}_p(\sqrt{t})$ we have $e=1$ and $f=2$, it is the unique extension among these three extensions with this property. But for both of  $\mathbb{Q}_p(\sqrt{p})$ and $\mathbb{Q}_p(\sqrt{pt})$ we have $e=2$ and $f=1$. Here I can not feel the difference between these two extensions.

Comment: You proved that $p$-adic extensions are not determined by $e,f$. The difference is that.. they are different, as seen in $\Bbb{Q}_p(\sqrt{p},\sqrt{tp})=\Bbb{Q}_p(\sqrt{p},\sqrt{t})$ which has $e=f=2$.

Comment: @reuns If we have $e=2$ and $f=1$, then I can just realize that $K_{\mathfrak{p}}$ is isomorphic to one of these two fields $\mathbb{Q}_p(\sqrt{p}), \mathbb{Q}_p(\sqrt{pt})$. Do you mean that with this information ($e=2$, $f=1$), it is not possible to choose the corresponding extension from these two extensions ($\mathbb{Q}_p(\sqrt{p}), \mathbb{Q}_p(\sqrt{pt})$)? I am a little bit confused.

Comment: Confused by what. Because it is Galois if $K=\Bbb{Q}[x]/(x^2-n)$ then $K_P$ is the splitting field of $x^2-n\in \Bbb{Q}_p$  thus either $\Bbb{Q}_p[x]/(x^2-n)$ or $\Bbb{Q}_p$ depending on irreducibility of $x^2-n$.

Comment: @reuns We just know $e=2$ and $f=1$, and we don't know $g$, and $K$ is not necessarily a quadratic extension. But your comment is very Illuminative for me. We have to write down $K$ as $K=\Bbb{Q}[x]/(P(x))$, and then we have to deal with $\Bbb{Q}_p[x]/(P(x))$ to understand $K_{\mathfrak{p}}$. Yet I can not determine the corresponding quadratic extension. I realized that if $p \nmid \text{Disc}(P(x))$, then simply we find $\mathbb{Q}_p(\sqrt{t})$ as the corresponding field (but this is not related to the case $e=2, f=1$)

Comment: $\sqrt{p}\in K_P$ iff $x^2-p$ has a root in $O_K/P^3$ iff $\pi_P^2 = a^2 p\bmod P^3$ with $a\not \in P$ and $\pi_P\in P,\not \in P^2$.

Answer (score 0):

@NeoTheComputer  For $p$ odd, $\mathbf Q_p^*/{\mathbf Q_p^*}^{2}\cong {C_2}^2$. This comes from the general canonical decomposition $\mathbf Q_p^* \cong p^{\mathbf Z} \times  \mathbf \mu_{p-1} \times (1+p\mathbf Z_p)$, which implies that $\mathbf Q_p^*/{\mathbf Q_p^*}^{2}$ is as announced, with representatives ${1, p, u, up}$, where $u$  is a unit s.t. $(u/p)=-1$ . See e.g. Serre's "A course in arithmetic", chap. I, §3.2. I misread completely your question.

NB: It seems to me that your question has been answered by Reuns. What does still bother you ?

Comment: What do you mean by ${C_p}^3$? By $C_p$ do you mean the cyclic group of order $p$? If yes, then it is not correct, and $\mathbf Q_p^*/{\mathbf Q_p^*}^{2}$ is the Klein Four group. Yet I can not understand, how your answer solves my question.

Comment: For $p\neq 2$, we have $\mathbf Q_p^*/{\mathbf Q_p^*}^{2}\cong {C_2}^2$. And for $p=2$, we have $\mathbf Q_p^*/{\mathbf Q_p^*}^{2}\cong {C_2}^3$.

Comment: My bad.I correct the misprint.

Comment: I misread completely your question. Because of the late hour here, I prefer not to risk more errors. I'll try to come back to your problem to-morrow. My apologies.